# How to identify the web button having same properties except the text content?

Tags: webdriver

I'm new to webdriver. When we delete the item then system shows the dialog window within frame where "OK" and "Cancel" button are displayed. Same dialog coming for add where "Ok" and cancel process with same XPath like `html/body/div[11]/div[3]/div/button[1]` and only difference is text content.

So, how can I write the xpath or css method?

Comment: `//some/xpath/locator[text()='mytext']` or `[contains(text(), 'my text')]` should help

Comment: <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only ui-state-focus ui-state-hover" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
<span class="ui-button-text">OK</span> I tried with above syntax also not working. 
</button>